# Metal - How to overlap textures based on color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, metal, blend

I'm trying to use a render pass descriptor to draw two grayscale textures. I am drawing a black square first, then a light gray square after. The second square partially covers the first.

With this setup, the light gray square will always appear in front of the black square because it was drawn most recently in the render pass. However, I would like to know if there is a way to draw the black square above the light gray one based on its brightness. Since the squares only partially overlap is there a way to still have the black square appear on top simply because it has a darker pixel value?

Currently it looks something like this, where the gray square is drawn second so it appears on top.
[image]

What I would like is to be able to still draw the gray square second, but have it appear underneath based on the pixel brightness, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think `MTLBlendOperationMin` will do what you want: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblendoperation/mtlblendoperationmin?language=objc